# notificationPublisher.PublishAsync is not sending notification to tenant

Tags: c#, multi-tenant, asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to send a notification to the tenant but nothing happens, not even record entered to the '[AbpNotifications]' table. I don't know where things went wrong.

```
using (UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(tenantId))
{
    var notificationData = new LocalizableMessageNotificationData(new LocalizableString("OverDueTaskManagementReminderMessage", DConsts.LocalizationSourceName));
    notificationData["a"] = "Accomplish By" + ws.WorkStream.AccomplishOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    notificationData["pn"] = user.Surname + "" + user.Name;
    notificationData["tmp"] = WorkStreamPriority.Urgent.ToString();

    AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(AppNotificationNames.OverDueTaskManagementReminder,
        notificationData, severity: NotificationSeverity.Info));

    UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Subscribed before publish and the code as below, this time notification didn't insert in host db nor in tenant db

await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(tenantId, (long)(AbpSession.UserId??1)),
                  AppNotificationNames.OverDueTaskManagementReminder);

```
            var result = _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(AppNotificationNames.OverDueTaskManagementReminder,
                notificationData, severity: NotificationSeverity.Info, tenantIds: new[] { tenantId }.Select(x => (int?)Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray()).IsCompleted;
                return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `tenantIds` explicitly to `PublishAsync` instead of `UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId`.
This will publish notifications to **subscribed** users in the `tenantIds` instead of the session's tenant.

```cs
AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(
    AppNotificationNames.OverDueTaskManagementReminder,
    notificationData,
    severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,
    tenantIds: new[] { tenantId } // Add this
));
```

## Explanation

Implementation detail: if both `tenantIds` and `userIds` are not set, then `PublishAsync` uses `AbpSession.TenantId`.

```cs
if (tenantIds.IsNullOrEmpty() && userIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    tenantIds = new[] { AbpSession.TenantId };
}
```